# Use join table data in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two tables: `user_nutrients` (that holds a user_id, nutrient_id and an amount as integer) and `nutrients` (that holds some more information on nutrients, like kcal, fat etc.). I want to create a "FoodCalculator" that takes the amount from `user_nutrients` and other data (let's say kcal) from `nutrients` to perform some calculations with it (multiply amount with kcal for my current user). I can retrieve all user_nutrients that belong to a certain user (through `def user_nutrients`) but my question is how I can now retrieve the corresponding data from the `nutrients` table in my FoodCalculator?

Been struggling with this now for several days. Sorry if my question may be too simple or not well explained. Just started coding few months ago.

**food_calculator.rb**

```
class FoodCalculator
  def initialize(user)
     @user = user
  end

  def user_nutrients
    @user_nutrients ||= @user.user_nutrients
  end
end
```

**nutrient.rb**

```
class Nutrient < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  has_many :user_nutrients
  has_many :users, through: :user_nutrients
end
```

**user_nutrient.rb**

```
class UserNutrient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :nutrient
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create :create_profile
  after_create :programstart

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :weights, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :programstarts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :user_nutrients
  has_many :nutrients, through: :user_nutrients


  private

  def programstart
    Programstart.create(:user_id => id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's Has many through relationship of user with nutrients

`@user_nutrients ||= @user.nutrients`

should work

Comment: Thx. Where do I have to put this?

Comment: also does User model have any association with UserNutrient ? if yes please add that to question as well

Comment: ok cool! the update works! however how can i now take the "amount" value on user_nutrients and multiply it with kcal from nutrients? still stuck with that. sorry again for asking simple questions. :-/

Comment: ok found a solution to my calculation problem. thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As you retrieve data from user by using `@user.user_nutrients`

In same manner you can retrieve by using `@nutrient.user_nutrients`

and if want find nutrients by user than you may use `@user.nutrients`

and you may also find users by nutrient than user `@nutrient.users`